# Scope within ES6 Classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I understand what is happening in the following snippet, and how to fix (with a binding or by making walk friend a method outside of the constructor), but why is this happening?  It seems counter intuitive to me to have to bind a class' scope to its own methods.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, friend) {
        this._name = name;
        if(friend) {
          this.walkFriend = friend.walk;
        }
    }
  
    get name() {
        return this._name.toUpperCase();
    }
  
    walk() {
        console.log(this.name + ' is walking.');
    }
}
         
let bob = new Person('Bob');
let bill = new Person('Bill', bob);

console.log(bob.name); // BOB
console.log(bill.name); // BILL
bill.walk() // Bill is walking.
bill.walkFriend(); // We expect 'BOB is walking', but we get 'BILL is walking.'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What's happening is that there is no intrinsic connection between a "method" in an ES2015 ("ES6") class and the instance, just like there isn't with the older style constructor functions.¹ `friend.walk` just returns a raw method reference, there's nothing about it that binds it to `friend` unless you do so yourself. Putting it another way, `friend.walk === Person.prototype.walk` is `true`. E.g., your counter-intuitive understanding is correct (except it's not about scope, but rather the value of `this`). :-)

Remember that the new `class` stuff is almost entirely just syntactic sugar (but, you know, the good kind of sugar). Your `Person` class almost exactly equates to this ES5 code:

```
var Person = function Person(name, friend) {
    this._name = name;
    if(friend) {
        this.walkFriend = friend.walk;
    }
};

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "name", {
    get: function() {
        return this._name.toUpperCase();
    },
    configurable: true
});

Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "walk", {
    value: function() {
        console.log(this.name + ' is walking.');
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

You've said you know how to solve it, and indeed both of your solutions will work, either binding:

```
constructor(name, friend) {
    this._name = name;
    if(friend) {
        this.walkFriend = friend.walk.bind(frield);   // **
    }
}
```

or creating `walk` within the constructor as an arrow function, instead of on the prototype:

```
constructor(name, friend) {
    this._name = name;
    this.walk = () => {                           // **
        console.log(this.name + ' is walking.');  // **
    };                                            // **
    if(friend) {
        this.walkFriend = friend.walk;
    }
}
```

---

¹ There *is* an intrinsic connection between the method and the *prototype* of the class it's defined within, which is used if you use the `super` keyword within the method. The spec calls that link the [[HomeObject]] field of the method (but you can't access it in code, and it can be optimized away by the JavaScript engine if you don't use `super` in the method).

Comment: @cswl: LOL! But note that that doesn't prevent a `Person` instance from keeping its associated `friend` in memory. Remember that it's only the **keys** in `WeakMap` and `WeakSet` that are held weakly, not the objects. So correct me if I'm wrong, but actually using a `WeakMap` here doesn't really help over just binding.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for that beautifully worded answer.  It was very clearly articulated.

Best,

Answer (score 3):

There are only 4 use cases of the `this` in JS. You might like to check [this](http://qr.ae/1mhiCF) for a good read. In this particular case you have an instruction `this.walkFriend = friend.walk;` which refers to the `walk` function in the object passed in by the `friend` argument. ***It's neither a new function definition nor belongs to the object it resides in***. It's just a referral to the function existing in the object referred as `friend`. However when you invoke it the `this` in the `friend.walk` function becomes the object from where it's been invoked. Hence you get the `name` property of the object referred by the `this`.

There are several ways to fix this. One as you would guess is bind. You can make it like `this.walkFriend = friend.walk.bind(friend);` or another is, to invoke it from within it's own scope like `this.walkFriend = _ => friend.walk();` (I presume since you use classes arrows should also be fine with you.)